# explicit instantiation but no definition available when build template function used by template class

Tags: c++11, templates, operator-keyword

```
#ifndef _QUEUE_HPP
#define _QUEUE_HPP
#include <iostream>
#include "Node.hpp"

namespace std{
  
  template<typename T>
  class Queue{
    public:
    class Node<T>* front;
    class Node<T>* rear;
    Queue();
    void enqueue(T data);
    T dequeue();
    ~Queue();
    template<class U>
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out,Queue<U> const& queue);
  };
  template<class classT>
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out,Queue<classT> const& queue);

  template class Queue<double>;
  
  template std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out,Queue<double> const& queue);
}
#endif
```

**Compile result**

g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp Stack.o Queue.o -o test

In file included from main.cpp:2:0:

Queue.hpp: In instantiation of ‘std::ostream& std::operator<<(std::ostream&, const std::Queue<classT>&) [with classT = double; std::ostream = std::basic_ostream<char>]’:

Queue.hpp:25:81:   required from here

Queue.hpp:25:81: error: explicit instantiation of ‘std::ostream& std::operator<<(std::ostream&, const std::Queue<classT>&) [with classT = double; std::ostream = std::basic_ostream<char>]’ but no definition available [-fpermissive]

mplate std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out,Queue<double> const& queue);

**Problem:**

**What happens with my code? I believe I have template operator<<being defined but the compiler can't find a definition.**

Comment: You have no definition of `operator<<` in your header file. It is needed for templates.

Comment: You should not add new definitions to the std namespace, ever.

Comment: But it’s a header file

Comment: Function implementation is in Queue.cap.This is Queue.hpp

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file

Comment: Explicit instantiation should go into a source file, not a header. The actual implementation of the template being instantiated should be visible at that point.